# Relate Plesk with Git

Tags: git, github, plesk

Can someone tell me how can i relate my project on Plesk (domain) with Git (gitlab).

I'm trying to relate manually my domain with git.

Before you proceed, please copy and paste the public part of the SSH key into your service (GitHub or BitBucket) used for the remote repository.

But can't change the SSH Key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change the SSH key. The provided key is the public part of a Plesk-generated key which shall be used to authenticate the connection to your remote git repository.
You're supposed to register the key in your git service so that the two parts can communicate securely.

It seems to only work with GitHub and BitBucket (?)
On GitHub, you just have to [add a new SSH key](https://github.com/settings/keys) associated with your account (paste *the public part of the SSH key* generated by Plesk into GitHub's *key* field).

See instructions here :
https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/website-management/git-support/using-remote-git-hosting.75848/